2 C: Drives, one with win 10 one with 11, trying to wipe the one with 10 through win 11
Well, like the long winded subject says, I'm encountering an interesting problem I haven't seen before, and I can't seem to find the answer I need.
I recently bought a m.2 with Windows 11 preinstalled (because my current C: drive is MBR not GPT, and I couldn't figure out how to change that without wiping it). Anyway, I copied my Windows 10 C: drive to a separate HDD I have, which is mostly unimportant to the issue I'm having. I'm just stating I backed up my drive.
Anyway, I can boot into Windows 10, if I remove the m.2 and can only boot into Windows 11 when it's connected. Disk Management shows my other 2 drives, but not my other C: drive (Windows 10). My thought is since both of these drives have windows on them, they are both showing up as C:, and Windows only recognizes the current OS booted as C:, which in this case is the m.2. This presents an issue for me, as I can't change the other drive to a different letter when booted in 10, and I just straight up can't see the drive when booted in 11.
I'm trying to wipe the Windows 10 drive, and migrate non Windows 10 OS files back on to it after format.
So, I suppose my question is "how do I detect this Windows 10 drive so I can format it while in windows 11?", because I'm almost certain Windows will not let me format the OS drive while booted to Windows 10.
Also, I am unsure, if it's safe to just unplug the Windows 10 drive while the pc is off, and plug it in while booted into 11 (all my drives are SATA SSDs) to try and get windows to assign it a new letter. Not trying to brick my PC over here, and that seems like a pretty convincing road to that solution.

“My thought is since both of these drives have windows on them, they are both showing up as C” - Your thought is flawed. Only the disk you boot to will be labeled with the drive letter C. If the other disk is not showing up in disk management something else is going on. Can you provide screenshots? It’s very unlikely your system supports hot swapping SATA. Do not plug in SATA drives while the system is turned on. If you do then you will cause a problem we cannot help you solve. Is there a reason you didn’t just use MBR2GPT?

Each OS has its own drive letter assigned to drives that OS sees. There isn't some table outside the OS storing drive letters and telling the OSes which is which. You can look at the serial numbers in Disk Management and Device Manager to confirm which drive is which. So long as you can boot into Windows 11 when the Windows 10 drive is disconnected from the computer, you should be able to check the drive SNs and format the Win10 one without issue while booted into Windows 11.

Wasn't aware mbr2gpt was a thing, I'll fire up windows 10 again and give that a shot, all I encountered when looking in to conversion was 3rd party apps that said they would need to wipe the drive.
